# I cannot append a matching pair to b:match_words

Tags: vimscript, plugin-matchit

I use `matchit.vim` and it works. Indeed I write a Fortran code and I can jump from `IF` to `END IF` pressing `%`.
I'm trying to add the couple `<+`, `>` to `b:match_words`,
adding

```
let b:match_words = b:match_words . '<+:>'
```

to my `~/.vimrc` file, but I get errors E121 and E15 bout undefined variable `b:match_words` and invalid expression `b:match_words . '<+:>'`, respectively.

If i change to

```
let b:match_words = '<+:>'
```

The error disappear, but obviously I cannot match anything else that this only pair.

Comment: Have you tried `let b:match_words += '<+:>'`? I think the `let` is necessary to declare a variable modification.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27549685/4082052

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I forgot the let in the question but used it in the code; now I edit the question.

Comment: Guys, string concatenation is `.`, not `+`.

Comment: You can try adding `let b:match_words .= ',<+:>'` to a `ftplugin` file (not to your `vimrc`).

Comment: I put in a `ftplugin` file the line @SatoKatsura suggested, but I still get the error E121.

Comment: Then try adding it to `after/ftplugin/fortran.vim`.

Comment: This was the problem!! Wait for you to post it as an answer. An explanation would be appreciated as well. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to extend `matchit`'s default `b:match_words`, so you'll have to to wait for it to be initialised first.  The docs make reference to setting it from `ftplugin`s, so the solution is to add

```
let b:match_words .= ',<+:>'
```

to a file `after/ftplugin/fortran.vim`.  That's about all there is to it.

On a side note: beware that `<+` and `>` above are actually regexps.  This is important if you want to add more pairs to `b:match_words`.

Comment: Do you mean that the pair I added should always be the last one?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I'm not sure I understand your point.  The pair you're adding is the last, yes.  How / why does that matter?

Comment: If I were going to add a pair, I would simply do `let b:match_words .= ',<+:>,hello:goodby'`. What's the problem with this new pair? (I supposed it is the order..)

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis There is nothing wrong with adding a new pair.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: So what did you mean by "beware that `<+` and `>` above are actually regexps. This is important if you want to add more pairs to `b:match_words`."? What should I be careful about?

Comment: `matchit` treats them as regexps.  If you want f.i. `[:]` you should write that as `\[:\]`.  If you want `item*:enditem*` you need to write it as `item\*:enditem\*`.   And so on.

Comment: Oh, sure! I misunderstood your note.